# Unable to Initialise tables in MVC-5 ERF-6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My code is like this

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using DiagnosisApp.Models;

namespace DiagnosisApp.DAL
{
    public class DiagnosisInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DiagnosisContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DiagnosisContext context)
        {
            var departments = new List<Department>
            {
                new Department {Name = "aks", CreatedUser = "rahul", CreatedDate = "2005-09-01"},
                new Department {Name = "john", CreatedUser = "rahul", CreatedDate = "2005-09-01"},
                new Department {Name = "ninoo", CreatedUser = "aks", CreatedDate = "2005-09-01"},
            };
            departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside my controller

```
   private DiagnosisContext db = new DiagnosisContext();
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Departments.ToList());
    }
```

and in Diagnosis context

```
    using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using DiagnosisApp.Models;

namespace DiagnosisApp.DAL
{
    public class DiagnosisContext : DbContext
    {
        public DiagnosisContext() : base("DiagnosisContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }


    }
}
```

and in webconfig

```
      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DiagnosisContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-DiagnosisApp-20150107051825.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-DiagnosisApp-20150107051825;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>



    <contexts>
    <context type="DiagnosisApp.DAL.DiagnosisContext, DiagnosisApp">
      <databaseInitializer type="DiagnosisApp.DAL.DiagnosisInitializer, DiagnosisApp" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
```

Everything looks okay to me. But this class is not initialising or ading this dummy data to DB. Can any one point out what I am missing here?

Note: I a new to MVC so following this tutorial to create my app
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: where do you set your Database Initializer in the DatabaseContext ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges fires Seed method only when your DB model changes. So if you add code to your seed method after you create database based on your current DB model, Seed method will not fired until you make changes on your model (for example adding new field to your Department class will cause model change).

You can use DropCreateDatabaseAlways strategy instead DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges if you want always fired Seed method.

Also take note that these both strategy useful only on test environment because obviosly drop/create DB leeds to data loss

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss this line of code in the constructor of your `DiagnosisContext`

```
public DiagnosisContext() : base("DiagnosisContext")
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DiagnosisInitializer());
}
```

Comment: I have tried like this
  public DiagnosisContext() : base("DiagnosisContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DiagnosisInitializer<DiagnosisContext>());
        }
but throws an error
The non-generic type 'DiagnosisApp.DAL.DiagnosisInitializer' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: Still not working. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application
  this is the tutorial I am following

Comment: No Error. Just data is not populating.

Comment: This tutorial uses the `web.config` file to glue the Initializer. did you add the `<databaseInitializer>` to your `web.config` file?

Comment: and `<contexts>` tag is inside `<entityFramework>` tag?

Comment: Yes. Its exactly as in Tutorial

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68460/discussion-between-ahmad-ibrahim-and-athul).